# Cannot create account using the EOSJS Create Account

Tags: eosjs, account-creation, error

eosjs 20.0.0

cannot create new account using the eosjs rpc call
see following code snippet below.

```
const addPrivateKey = "EOS8i1CXTY4Sz39XaQWX2RpccsCZ1nWM3w9zRhjCFChdci2Y65ck4";
const rpc = new eosjs_jsonrpc.JsonRpc('http:///[ip address]:8888');
const signatureProvider = new eosjs_jssig.JsSignatureProvider([addPrivateKey]);
const api = new eosjs_api.Api({ rpc, signatureProvider });

var returnmsg = "";
//alert("before async");

/(async () => {
try {
result = await rpc.get_info();
//const result = await rpc.get_account('alice');
//const result = await rpc.get_currency_balance('eosio.token', 'alice', 'SYS');
returnmsg += '\n\nTransaction pushed!\n\n' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
console.log(returnmsg);
} catch (e) {
returnmsg = '\nCaught exception: ' + e;
if (e instanceof eosjs_jsonrpc.RpcError)
returnmsg += '\n\n' + JSON.stringify(e.json, null, 2);
console.log(returnmsg);
}
})();/

(async () => {
try {
const result = await api.transact({
actions: [{
account: 'eosio',
name: 'newaccount',
authorization: [{
actor: 'eosio',
permission: 'active',
}],
data: {
creator: 'eosio',
name: 'testnewaccount',
owner: {
threshold: 1,
keys: [{
key: 'EOS8i1CXTY4Sz39XaQWX2RpccsCZ1nWM3w9zRhjCFChdci2Y65ck4',
weight: 1
}],
accounts: [],
waits: []
},
active: {
threshold: 1,
keys: [{
key: 'EOS8i1CXTY4Sz39XaQWX2RpccsCZ1nWM3w9zRhjCFChdci2Y65ck4',
weight: 1
}],
accounts: [],
waits: []
},
},
}]
}, {
blocksBehind: 3,
expireSeconds: 30,
});
console.log(result);
} catch (e) {
returnmsg = '\nCaught exception: ' + e;
if (e instanceof eosjs_jsonrpc.RpcError)
returnmsg += '\n\n' + JSON.stringify(e.json, null, 2);
console.log(returnmsg);
}
}
)();
```

should be able to create an account using the following from web to /vi/chain/

OS/browser:

> OS: [e.g. iOS]: Windows 10 Browser [e.g. chrome, safari]: Chrome
>   Version [e.g. 22]: Version 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Additional details below:
[‎4/‎10/‎2019 8:40 PM] DelaCruz, Ericko:

> No Title Angular CLI: 7.3.8 Node: 10.15.3 OS: win32 x64 Angular:
>   7.2.12 ... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms ... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic ...
>   router

Package Version

```
@angular-devkit/architect 0.13.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular 0.13.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer 0.13.8
@angular-devkit/build-webpack 0.13.8
@angular-devkit/core 7.3.8
@angular-devkit/schematics 7.3.8
@angular/cli 7.3.8
@ngtools/webpack 7.3.8
@schematics/angular 7.3.8
@schematics/update 0.13.8
rxjs 6.3.3
typescript 3.2.4
webpack 4.29.0
```

Are we missing some parameters in the above json request?

Comment: A clear hint is that `EOS8i...` is the public key, however, it is called private key in the font. For security reasons, please don't post a real private key you use though!

Comment: Can you post the error message?  Use the private key like suggested above.  I ran into many issues throughout the betas for eosjs 20 so maybe something simple is tripping it. I know their docs were outdated at one point.

Answer (score 2):

In the first line you're entering an EOS public key in what should be a private key

```
const addPrivateKey = "EOS8i1CXTY4Sz39XaQWX2RpccsCZ1nWM3w9zRhjCFChdci2Y65ck4";
```

Change this to the private key but as the comments say, be sure you keep this private, don't upload it or anything.